# The content of bottles of water follows a normal distribution with average = 0.99 and standard deviation 0.02. Find the variance of sample

Tags: probability, statistics

> The content in litres of bottled water follows a normal distribution
>   with average 0.99 and standard deviation of 0.02.
>
> a) Suppose a sample of 16 bottles is chosen. Determine the probability
>   that the average content of the sample is greater than 1 litre.
>
> b) Determine the size of the sample so that the probability that the
>   difference between the average of the sample and the average of the
>   population doesn't exceed 0.01 is at least 0.95.

My professor solved a) this way:
[image]

Why did he use $\frac{0.02^2}{16}$ for the variance and not just $0.02^2$?

He solved b) this way:

[image]

I don't understand why he used the given mean 0.99 and for the variance he used $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. Why do I have to estimate the variance if the variance is the stdev^2 and the stdev is given?

Answer (score 2):

I assume the sample is supposed to be independent. I denote the content of the 16 sampled bottles by $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{16}$.

Regarding your first question: The variance of the sample mean is 
$$\operatorname{Var}(\bar{X})=\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{1}{16}\sum_{i=1}^{16}{X_i}\right)=\frac{1}{16^2}\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{16} {X_i}\right)=\frac{1}{16^2}\sum_{i=1}^{16}\operatorname{Var}(X_i)=\frac{1}{16^2} 16\cdot 0.02^2 = \frac{0.02^2}{16},$$ where we have used independence and the [rules for the variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties).

The same reasoning applies to (b). By the same steps as above (just replace 16 by $n$) you can show that the variance of the sample mean is equal $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ and hence the standard deviation is $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. Note that the variance of the sample mean does not equal to the variance of the underlying distribution (except if $n=1$ or the variance of the underlying distribution is $0$).

The expected value on the other hand is the same, which the following calculation shows:
$$\mathbb{E}(\bar{X})=\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left(X_i\right)=\frac{1}{n}n\cdot0.99=0.99,$$ where we have used the [linearity of the expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties).

That's how your prof got the expected value and the standard deviation for the sample average.

To think about this intuitively, imagine we collect a very small sample (so $n$ is small). Each observation carries much weight in the sample average (especially unusually small or large observations). If we draw repeated small samples, our sample average will hence vary a lot. If we have a very large sample ($n$ large), then we gonna observe all kinds of observation (most of them in a range that has much probability mass) and a few extreme observations won't move the sample average by much. If we draw repeated large samples, our sample average will not vary a lot. So, we would intuitively assume that the variance decreases as the sample size increases (indeed $n$ shows up in the denominator).